# "How to have the user add two random integers on a single page using $_POST"

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create an adding game PHP and HTML, where the user guesses the sum of two random integers. However, when the user submits the answer, the integers randomize again, changing the sum and making the user's guess incorrect.

```
<?php
  $x = (rand(1,10));
  $y = (rand(1,10));
  $sum = $x + $y;
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
     $guess = $_POST['guess'];
     if ($sum == $guess)
     {
        echo "nice, you got it right.";
     }
     else {
        echo "aw, too bad. <br>";
     }
  }
  echo "<br>What is " . $x . " + " . $y . "? <br>";?>  

  <form action="" method="post">
       <input name="guess" type="text" />
       <input name="submit" type="submit" />
  </form>
```

I am expecting the output to be "nice, you got it right" when the `$guess==$sum`, but $sum changes when the form is submitted, making the 2 variables unequal.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use session and store the two random number. [PHP Session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

just like this.

```
<?php

session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $sum = $_SESSION['y'] + $_SESSION['x'];
     $guess = $_POST['guess'];
                if ($sum == $guess)
                    {
                    echo "nice, you got it right.";
                    }
                else {
                    echo "aw, too bad. <br>";
                    }
  }
  $_SESSION['x']= (rand(1,10));
  $_SESSION['y']= (rand(1,10));
echo "<br>What is " . $_SESSION['x'] . " + " . $_SESSION['y'] . "? <br>";
    ?>  

<form action="" method="post">
<input name="guess" type="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I hope I answer your problem. just read the PHP session it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hidden input field to post the sum value. Then compare that value with the guessed value.

```
<?php
  $x = (rand(1,10));
  $y = (rand(1,10));
  $sum = $x + $y;
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $guess = $_POST['guess'];
    $value = $_POST['sum'];
    if ($value == $guess) {
      echo "nice, you got it right.";
    } else {
      echo "aw, too bad. <br>";
    }
  }
  echo "<br>What is " . $x . " + " . $y . "? <br>";
?>  
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="guess" type="text" />
<input type="hidden" name="sum" value="<?=$sum?>" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store your $x and $y in a hidden input.
Calculate the sum by using the post value instead of generating new value.